# Just updated to Django 1.4 and getting 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'SUCCESS' error

Tags: django

I just upgraded to Django 1.4 and am getting the following error:

`'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'SUCCESS'`

Traceback:

```
File "/Users/nb/Desktop/myenv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/nb/Desktop/spicestore/apps/account/views.py" in login
  87.             messages.add_message(request.SUCCESS,

Exception Type: AttributeError at /account/login/
Exception Value: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'SUCCESS'
```

Anyone know what could be causing it?

Here's the actual code in views.py:

```
 messages.add_message(request.SUCCESS,
        ugettext(u"Successfully logged in as %(user)s.") % {
            "user": user_display(form.user)
        }
```

Comment: The request object has never had an attribute `SUCCESS`. Where is it supposed to be coming from?

Answer (score 0):

```
messages.add_message(request, 
                 messages.SUCCESS, 
                 ugettext(u"Successfully logged in as %(user)s.") % { "user": user_display(form.user) })
```

or FASTER:

```
messages.success(request, 
                 ugettext(u"Successfully logged in as %(user)s.") % { "user": user_display(form.user) })
```

See:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/#using-messages-in-views-and-templates